# VSCode: Any way to convert line wrapping into newline characters?

Tags: editor, sublimetext3, visual-studio-code, atom-editor

Trying to format my code using VSCode and need the line wrapping to actually persist in GIT, so the line wrapping needs to change the source code itself.

(don't worry about giving me advise on how this is a bad idea. I have a special use case for this - publishing)

Anyone know how to get this done? Or if this is possible with another editor or plugin, I am open to that as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Your question only asks about VSCode but you have tagged sublime text 3 as well; did you mean to do that?

Comment: Yes, I did. Because if the solution was to open those set of files in another editor and do it there, then come back to VsCode, I'd be ok with that. In fact, look at my post closer. It says: "Or if this is possible with **another editor** or plugin, I am open to that as well."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is hard wrapping.

This functionality is not included in VSCode to my knowledge, but there are a [few extensions that add this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=hard%20wrap&target=VSCode&sortBy=Relevance). Try [Rewrap](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stkb.rewrap) to start with: `ext install rewrap`:

[image]

Comment: Great! Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!